# Is there a difference between `(i === true)` and `(i)`?

Tags: javascript

I'm messing with code that someone else wrote and I saw that he writes like this

```
if(i === true)
```

Is there a difference if I do it this way?

```
if(i)
```

Comment: the former is a strict comparison and will check if `i` is an actual boolean true value. The latter will return true if `i` is any value that will evaluate true (truthy value), e.g. 1 will evaluate as true

Comment: thank you very much for your answer
I think you should post this as an answer

Comment: I just want to know if this is the only difference

Comment: I would rather this be marked as a duplicate. Lots of existing questions asking the same thing :)

Comment: To add to @CrayonViolent, (i) is the same as (i == true) so the question really is == vs ===. And there are a bunch of questions related to that.

Comment: @Agoodperson "I just want to know if this is the only difference" - As far as your example is concerned, yes.

Comment: I didn't understand your question probably because of translation problems

Comment: See also: "[Is there ever a reason to write "if (myBoolean == true)" in a JavaScript conditional?](/q/13250176/90527)", "[Why aren't results of logical-not and strict comparison inverses of each other?](/q/13127126/90527)", "[Why is it good practice to use if (myBoolean === true) in JavaScript?](/q/13250664/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first if statement is checking for exact equality, and will only run if `i` was exactly equal to true.

The second one is checking for whether `i` is truthy, which means the if statement would still run if `i` was something other than things such as `null`, `undefined`, or an empty string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: I think in the second case you meant "would still run if `i` was *something other than* things such as `null`, ..."

Comment: @user19513069 you’re right, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comparison operator will return true if i is boolean true, but just having i will return true for any truthy value I.E: positive integers, non-empty strings, etc